# Error when trying to find a string in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find an ID in a dataframe column.

If it exists then the new df will be converted to the correspondent one, but it raises an error.

Where could be the mistake?

```py
df = pd.read_excel('somefile.xlsx')
ids = df['ID'].to_list()

for id in ids:
  if id in ids:
    df_arc = df_arc.set_index('ID')
    df_arc=df_arc.loc[id]
  else:
    print('It is not here')
```

This is the error I receive:

```py
KeyError: "None of ['ID'] are in the columns"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df["ID"]` will try to access the ID column - that you **don't** have.

If you refer to the rows index, then you can just change this statement with:

```py
ids = df.index.to_list()
```